# fatal error: 'GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h' file not found in flutter IOS build

Tags: flutter, google-maps, dart

I just created a new flutter project and add these two libraries

```
  google_maps_flutter: ^1.2.0
  google_map_location_picker: ^4.1.6
```

and in my `AppDelegate.m` file I added this code

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "GeneratedPluginRegistrant.h"
#import "GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h"

@implementation AppDelegate
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
      [GMSServices provideAPIKey:@"MY API KEY"];
        [GeneratedPluginRegistrant registerWithRegistry:self];
      // Override point for customization after application launch.
      return [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
}

@end
```

and in my `Info.plist` file I added permission strings too

```
    <key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>This app needs access to location when open and in the background.</string>
    <key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
    <string>This app needs access to location when in the background.</string>
    <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>This app needs access to location when open.</string>
```

This is my current flutter SDK Version `1.22.5`
This is my current Dart version `2.10.4`

Now, when I build this project this is the error I am getting in Flutter SDK:

```
 /Users/umarghaffar/flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/google_maps_flutter-1.2.0/ios/Classes/JsonConversions.h:6:9:
 fatal error: 'GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h' file not found
    #import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>
```

I tried everything that is possible and searched the internet but didn't find anything. I was working on previous projects that used google map library but I thought there is some issue in my project then I created a new project and just simply imported these two libraries and this error occurs while building the project. There is no error while install Pods. There must be an error in my flutter SDK.

Answer (score 3):

**This worked for me**

1. remove the `google_maps_flutter` dependency inside `pubspec.yaml`
2. run `flutter pub get`
3. add the `google_maps_flutter` dependency again
4. run `flutter pub get`

Answer (score 1):

This could be an issue of you not copying the frameworks to the project folder, and then after adding the GoogleMaps framework maybe you moved the framework file on your computer to a new location?

Try deleting the framework from your project and then adding the framework again by going to your Project's Build Setting --> Build Phases and dragging the framework into that window.

Also, perform a Project Clean, and make sure that if you have an iOS Simulator running (in any project) to stop it and close it.

Sometimes this causes Xcode to freeze the update process within the coding.